# Can you request to have more than 5 apps per org in salesforce

Tags: lightning, community, mobile, mobile-publisher

Were planning to create multiple apps with Mobile publisher but there is a limit of 5 apps per org. Is there a way to add more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently we faced a similar issue, although our limit was 10 apps. Anyway you can open a case to Salesforce support to ask them for increasing your limit

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of 5 community apps and 1 internal application. You can raise a case with support to get it increased. There might be a cost involved.

Unfortunately once an app is created, it cannot be deleted to free your license limit.